# Sort DataTable by an specific string

Tags: jquery, datatables

Just a simple question:

How can I sort a column called "Status" by ordering all the rows that contains the word "New" first?
This is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main-table').DataTable({
        "order": [[4, 'desc']]
    });
})


ID  Name  LastName Status
01  John  Carmarck Old
01  John  Tobias   Old
01  John  Romero   New
01  Shi   Miyamoto In Process
```

Thank you

Comment: add some code..

Comment: you need to give more detail.  Show the table you are trying to sort with some sample data, even a couple of lines would help.

Comment: And this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32564115/4843530.  At least that answer should give you enough to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: elaborate your question by adding client side or server side datatable are you using?

Answer (score 0):

try to change your status td as

```
<td data-sort="New"></td>
```

and remove other shorting logic.